# How to replace the values of nested lists stored in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested

I have the following dataframe

```
data = [[[[[1, 2, 0], [1]],[[1, 2], [4]]],
        [[[[1, 2], [4]]]], [[[1]]]], [[[[1, 2, 0], [1]],[[1, 2], [4]]],
        [[[[1, 2], [4]]]], [[[1]]]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Also, I have a second dataframe `df2`:

```
data2 = [[1, 10], [1, 15], [1, 14], [1, 20], [1, 18]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['dir', 'line'])
```

The values of the nested lists of `df` represent the `Index` of `df2`. I would like to replace the values of the nested lists of `df` with the values of the column line of `df2`. The expected output is the following:

```
finalData = [[[[[15, 14, 10], [15]],[[15, 14], [20]]],
        [[[[15, 14], [20]]]], [[[15]]]], [[[[15, 14, 10], [15]],[[15, 14], [20]]],
        [[[[15, 14], [29]]]], [[[15]]]]]

finaldf = pd.DataFrame(finalData)
```

Comment: Do you need a `pandas` solution? I can offer a recursive function in standard Python.

Comment: @C-3PO I would like to store my results in a dataframe. But feel free to share your solution. Thanks

Comment: You will have to loop anyway as it's nearly impossible to vectorize when you have lists in pandas. So python is the way to go.

Comment: @mozway You are right. I was thinking to apply a replace function for each cell of the dataframe. That's what I need I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```py
data = [[[[[1, 2, 0], [1]],[[1, 2], [4]]],
        [[[[1, 2], [4]]]], [[[1]]]], [[[[1, 2, 0], [1]],[[1, 2], [4]]],
        [[[[1, 2], [4]]]], [[[1]]]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data2 = [[1, 10], [1, 15], [1, 14], [1, 20], [1, 18]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['dir', 'line'])

def fn(index):
    if isinstance(index, list):
        return [fn(i) for i in index]
    else:
        return df2['line'][index]

final = df.applymap(fn)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this recursive solution

```
data = [[[[[1, 2, 0], [1]],[[1, 2], [4]]],
        [[[[1, 2], [4]]]], [[[1]]]], [[[[1, 2, 0], [1]],[[1, 2], [4]]],
        [[[[1, 2], [4]]]], [[[1]]]]]
data2 = [[1, 10], [1, 15], [1, 14], [1, 20], [1, 18]]
def new_data(data, data2):
  res = []
  for i in data:
    if isinstance(i, list):
      res.append(new_data(i, data2))
    else:
      res.append(data2[i][1])
  return res
final_data = new_data(data, data2)
print(final_data)

# output: 
[[[[[15, 14, 10], [15]], [[15, 14], [18]]], [[[[15, 14], [18]]]], [[[15]]]],
     [[[[15, 14, 10], [15]], [[15, 14], [18]]], [[[[15, 14], [18]]]], [[[15]]]]]
```

Comment: Many thanks! Do you have any suggestion for storing the results in a dataframe as well ?(the one that I proposed as a df)

Comment: Can you give an example to elaborate your point.

Comment: @ assume_irrational_is_rational. I want to save the result in a dataframe. I actually would like to replace the values of df based on the values of a specific column from df2 as I describe in my question